# How the diffraction occurs in cassegrain telescope?

Tags: astrophysics, instrument

I know about the diffraction limit of a telescope. But please explain through diagram how diffraction occurs in Cassegrain telescope which has both primary as well as a secondary reflector.

Comment: diagram; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassegrain_reflector#/media/File:Cassegrain.en.png

Comment: article; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassegrain_reflector

Comment: I read through the page. But, my question was how diffraction occurs in reflection circular aperture telescope. We are very well familiar with diffraction through the circular slot. And we also know this - http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/diflim.html